# SO not showing any <title>'s

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, title, mobile-web

Every page I view on SO is producing an empty `<title>`.  I'm on my iPad 2 using safari.  MSO `<title>`'s are working fine.  Is this a known issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: After restarting, some titles appear, some don't.  Maybe its just an issue with my iPad..

Comment: not able to reproduce the error .

Comment: Are the tags present in the page source?

Comment: That's strange, if a page doesn't have a title surely the iPad like most browsers shows you some other useful information in the tab - like the URL. I've never seen a "blank" tab title.

Comment: @B Yes, which is proof now that its a problem with my iPad. Sorry for the false alarm all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this on any of our iPads.